# Cannot mount DVD+RW written by dvd recorder

Tags: linux, mount, dvd

I have recorded a DVD from TV, using a common DVD recorder. I can read it on any DVD recorder, but I cannot read it on my PC. I am using Manjaro Linux.

The disk is DVD+RW.

Googling, I have found many questions like this one, but I did not find a solution for me yet.

The disk is not automounted. If I try to manually mount it, it fails:

```
[luke@pc-luca Scaricati]$ sudo mount /dev/sr0 /mnt
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

(similar issues with `-t udf` or `-t iso9660`)

However, the OS can "see" the disk:

```
[luke@pc-luca Scaricati]$ dvd+rw-mediainfo /dev/sr0
INQUIRY:                [HL-DT-ST][DVDRAM GUD0N    ][1.00]
GET [CURRENT] CONFIGURATION:
 Mounted Media:         1Bh, DVD+R
 Media ID:              CMC MAG/M01
 Current Write Speed:   8.0x1385=11080KB/s
 Write Speed #0:        8.0x1385=11080KB/s
 Write Speed #1:        4.0x1385=5540KB/s
 Speed Descriptor#0:    00/15871 R@8.0x1385=11080KB/s W@8.0x1385=11080KB/s
 Speed Descriptor#1:    00/15871 R@8.0x1385=11080KB/s W@4.0x1385=5540KB/s
READ DVD STRUCTURE[#0h]:
 Media Book Type:       00h, DVD-ROM book [revision 0]
 Legacy lead-out at:    2295104*2KB=4700372992
READ DISC INFORMATION:
 Disc status:           appendable
 Number of Sessions:    1
 State of Last Session: incomplete
 "Next" Track:          1
 Number of Tracks:      2
READ TRACK INFORMATION[#1]:
 Track State:           reserved
 Track Start Address:   0*2KB
 Next Writable Address: 0*2KB
 Free Blocks:           15872*2KB
 Track Size:            15872*2KB
READ TRACK INFORMATION[#2]:
 Track State:           invisible
 Track Start Address:   15888*2KB
 Next Writable Address: 103488*2KB
 Free Blocks:           2191616*2KB
 Track Size:            2279216*2KB
 ROM Compatibility LBA: 266240
READ CAPACITY:          0*2048=0
```

Any idea? Thank you.

**Edit:**

```
[luke@pc-luca Scaricati]$ file /dev/sr0
/dev/sr0: block special (11/0)
```

(same output is given with no CD inside the drive)

and

```
[luke@pc-luca Scaricati]$ sudo mount -o offset=$((15888*2048)) /dev/sr0 /mnt
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

**Edit n.2**

dd fails:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sr0 of=MYFILE bs=2k
dd: errore leggendo '/dev/sr0': Errore di input/output
0+0 record dentro
0+0 record fuori
0 bytes copied, 0,133062 s, 0,0 kB/s

$ dd if=/dev/sr0 of=MYFILE seek=$((15888*2048)) bs=2k
dd: errore leggendo '/dev/sr0': Errore di input/output
0+0 record dentro
0+0 record fuori
0 bytes copied, 0,125784 s, 0,0 kB/s
```

Comment: You have an incomplete session with data, I'm not sure if the kernel does mount that. What does `file /dev/sr0` say? Can you copy the track with the incomplete session to disk, and try to mount that? (That would test if it's a format problem, or a problem with the session).

Comment: Thank you all. @dirkt, what you mean with "copy the track with the incomplete session to disk" ? How can I do that?

Comment: IIRC from forever ago when CD-R first became affordable you had to close session, and then if you wanted to you could finalize the entire disc.  Based on the output in your question, looks like a session isn't closed....